# What is anti-time?

Tags: spacetime

I've been trying to wrap my mind around the concept of [anti-time](http://www.google.com/search?q=anti-time) and wondered what it is. If there is anti-matter and anti-gravity, does time have its negative? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as anti-time in physics - yet. 
It is time traveling in the other `direction`. Just as time is matter and space by themselves, it will not be observed in the same side of the context. No matter can move in that direction because once it gets to that space, it gets canceled out with the anti-matter. However, if you can `make` anti-matter, it will work accordingly on that time-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as anti-time in physics. (Neither is there anti-space or anti-gravity.) Antimatter is a very specific term, namely for particles that have the same properties but opposite quantum numbers (charges) as the "regular" particles. Sometimes, antimatter refers only to molecules build from anti-particles.

If you just slap "anti-" on a random physical concept, it does not have to have a meaning :-).